f ,differentiable on a bounded open set S, continuous on the closure of S, and constant on the boundary of S then there is some c$\in$S ,$\nabla f=0$
Here $f$ is $f:S\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and question wants me to claim and prove a statement and i claimed:
Claim: Then there exists some $c\in S$ such that $\nabla$$f(c)=0$
First let $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in\partial$S
Case that where for all $x\in$S, $f(x)=c$ and we are done.
If not then we know that S is bounded and since $f$ is defined on $\partial$S then S is also closed hence its compact since we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then so does $f(S)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and f is continuous on S then we can conclude that $f$ takes it's maximum and minimum values on some $c_{max}$$\in$S, $c_{min}$$\in$S.
And at these points $\nabla f(c_{max})=\nabla f(c_{min})=0$.
After that i concluded my proof but can we extend the claim as there are at least two points that satisfy $\nabla$$f=0$

why does $f$ defined on $\partial S$ imply that $S$ is closed? If this is the case, then $S$ is the empty set

No, consider $S$ to be the unit ball and $f(x)=\|x\|^2$. Then there is only one solution to your problem, namely the center of the ball. In order to get your claim you need to assume that $f(S)$ contains both points above and below $c$.

So does my proof have a problem where i said that at both $c_{max}$ and $c_{min}$ the gradient of f is 0.

Yes, you can be sure that the gradient will be zero only if the maximum/minimum is in the interior, which will happen for sure if this maximum/minimum is different from $c$.
